# XMLHttpRequest does not work in Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, microsoft-edge

Here is the code I am using

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4) {
       // Typical action to be performed when the document is ready:
       var xmlOBJ = xhttp.responseXML;
    }
};
xhttp.open("GET", "filename", true);
xhttp.send();
```

If I run this under IE10 or below it works. If I run it under Firefox or Safari, it works. It won't work under Chrome but that is a know issue and currently isn't resolved. However I am suprised this doesn't work under Microsoft Edge. What is more surprising is that I can't find anything that confirms this. So I'm thinking I have forgetten something quite trival when it comes to Microsoft Edge. Has anyone else run into this issue and have found a way to resolve it? The error is that xhttp.responseXML is null. I ran the same code under IE and it works fine.

Thanks!

Comment: is the page loaded using `file:///` or `http://` protocol?

Comment: `IE10 or below` - what about IE11?

Comment: what is Content-Type of response? Is it xml?

Comment: What does `xhttp.status` property return?

Comment: Page is loaded using file. This is a client side file getting loaded. Works in IE 11.  Content is xml. Status always returns 0.

Comment: Any other ideas? I accidentally flagged a comment so I'm wondering if that may have deterred other ideas. :)